# Looking for a fantasy story - People with inborn magic

Tags: story-identification

#### Chronology and other relevant information

I read it at the latest in the mid 90s, which means it would most likely written before that. I remember multiple books, none particularly large.

#### Plot Points

1. It involved the main protagonist who initially discovers he has the power to control fire (Which is rare but not impossible - **someone refers to him as a "Firebrand"**) but eventually discovers he has more broad elemental powers which was either unique or at least ultra rare.
2. He gets together with other people with these powers to overthrow some sort of evil.
3. I think one of his companions had some control over poison.

Comment: Can you recall any other details?

Comment: Trying to think of something but it was so long ago! I think one of his companions had some control over poison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is [Blade of the Poisoner](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/689341.Blade_of_the_Poisoner) by Douglas Hill.

The protagonist Jarral is wounded by the villain (the "Poisoner") and rescued by a wizard and 3 companions with special powers ("Talents").

> About half way through the book Jarral discovers he can summon fire and is called a Firebrand. At the end in the climatic battle, it is revealed he can actually summon Elementals.

It was published in 1987 and is short YA (or younger) novel. There is a sequel called Master of Fiends.

Comment: This could be it.

Comment: This sounds like it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Brightly Burning by Mercedes Lackey? From the [Google Books description](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Brightly_Burning.html?id=HQYbPwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Lavan Chitward is a very unhappy young man; pulled away from his
>   country home by his parents' ambitions and resettled in the big city
>   of Haven, he is desperately lonely, bullied and beaten at school,
>   ignored by his parents. It is not surprising that he falls ill -- but
>   his illness is the first manifestation of a terrible power, the Gift
>   of the Firestorm, a power which can and does kill. If controlled, the
>   Gift of the Firestorm can save Valdemar, but if it is uncontrolled, it
>   will destroy the country -- and him. Chosen by the Companion Kalira,
>   brought into the ranks of the Heralds of Valdemar, Lavan finds
>   acceptance and hope for the first time. But war with Karse threatens
>   to engulf the Kingdom and only Lavan Firestorm stands between Valdemar
>   and destruction -- and only then if he can harness his dreadful power
>   to his will.

Comment: I don't think its this, because his association with fire goes away pretty quickly when it turns out he has more broad elemental powers.